# What could be the use of forking a repository in a github's organization?

Tags: git, github, workflows

I'm trying to figure it out some nice workflow for our company, and we have so far the main  repository on the github's organization account and we all, the members of the team working on the branches of that repo.

Could you please mention some advantages on forking the repo or some use, by the members of the organization?

I was thinking, that for example, I could make a fork and perform a upgrade of the libraries, but  someone pointed that, "what is the differences on doing it simply in another branch,without forking?

Thank you in advance, for your time.

Comment: Related: [github team workflow - to fork or not?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88099/github-team-workflow-to-fork-or-not?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The main benefit of github forking is allowing a gatekeeper workflow, where untrusted people can work on a feature and a trusted gatekeeper pulls it in after a review.  That model is not very popular within a company, because employees are generally considered trusted.

However, it can be useful if you want an experienced employee to control who can change certain parts of the code, or if you want a repository that only contains commits that QA signed off on, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Karl's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/199972/500), pull requests are a good place to discuss the code added since each individual pull request have their own comment thread that is also markdown supported. This serves as a good form of documentation when you're trying to find out the reason behind a certain change in the codebase.